# Display random div from X divs selected by CSS-Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have, on a homepage, X html div elements in one page, with X different classnames:

- class="home-1"
- class="home-2"
- class="home-3"
- class="home-4"
- etc.

My goal is, to dislpay only one of these "divs" randomly, so when the page is refreshing, everytime a randomly different div is displayed. The rest should be hidden.
it would be very nice if the same div was not shown twice in a row 
I think, i can't do this, only with css.

what i manually can do is

```
.home-1 { display: none; }
.home-3 { display: none; }
.home-4 { display: none; }
```

So in this Case home-2 is displayed.

Of course i want that automated with javascript, can someone please help me?

that yould be very nice!

Comment: Is the class always going to be in this format: `home-n` where n is a number?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  You are expected to have made an attempt, and demonstrate a [mcve] for us to help you with debugging.  Otherwise this is a coding request and is off topic.

Comment: @Taplar I did some research befor and there was no similar questions, dont know what your problem is...

Comment: As I stated, the question has not provided a visible attempt at solving the question already.  Without such, we can only assume that you are simply asking for a solution, thus a coding request.  Which is off topic for the site.  The first post I linked to talks about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.random() and seed it with the number of elements you have:

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll(".home")

let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * els.length)

els[num].style.display = "inline-block"
```

```css
.home{display: none; padding: 15px}

.home-1{background-color: lightblue}
.home-2{background-color: yellow}
.home-3{background-color: pink}
.home-4{background-color: seagreen;color:#fff}
```

```html
<div class="home home-1">1</div>
<div class="home home-2">2</div>
<div class="home home-3">3</div>
<div class="home home-4">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the class randomly, then hide all except the element with the random class:

```js
var classList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class^=home-]')).map(el => el.className);
var random = classList[Math.floor(Math.random() * classList.length)];
document.querySelectorAll(`[class^=home-]:not(.${random})`).forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<div class="home-1">home-1</div>
<div class="home-2">home-2</div>
<div class="home-3">home-3</div>
<div class="home-4">home-4</div>
<div class="home-5">home-5</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet won't run on stackoverflow because you aren't allowed to access the local storage. But it should work fine in your environment.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=home-]');
const lastIndex = Number(localStorage.getItem('lastElement'));
let randomIndex = lastIndex;

do {
  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
} while (randomIndex === lastIndex);

const randomElement = elements[randomIndex];
randomElement.style.display = 'block';

localStorage.setItem('lastElement', randomIndex);
```

```css
div[class^=home-] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-1">home-1</div>
<div class="home-2">home-2</div>
<div class="home-3">home-3</div>
<div class="home-4">home-4</div>
<div class="home-5">home-5</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all div elements that start with the class name 'home-', then generate a random number between 0 and X and check localStorage or sessionStorage for the last saved div number and keep generating numbers if the new random number was the previous.

See below (The script will not run because localStorage won't work here - on SO):

```js
function randomize() {
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="home"]');
  let length = divs.length;
  let currDiv = localStorage.getItem("divActive");
  
  rand = getNextRndm(currDiv, length);
  
  for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if(i != rand) {
      divs[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      divs[i].style.display = "block";
      localStorage.setItem("divActive", rand);
    }
  }
}

function getNextRndm(currDiv, length) {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

  if(currDiv !== null) {
    while(rand == currDiv)
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  }
  return rand;
}

randomize();
```

```html
<div class="home-1">1st div</div>
<div class="home-2">2nd div</div>
<div class="home-3">3rd div</div>
<div class="home-4">4th div</div>
```